# Firebase AsyncTask fatal exception

Tags: firebase, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

In my project I am working with **Firebase** and **sometimes** (not every time) when I run my app I am getting exception: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15`. I don't have idea why, but I think it may be related to Firebase. My full log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: pl.project.project, PID: 21825
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:468)
    at com.facebook.appevents.RestrictiveDataManager.updateFromSetting(RestrictiveDataManager.java:46)
    at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.parseAppSettingsFromJSON(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:323)
    at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.queryAppSettings(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:286)
    at com.facebook.UserSettingsManager$1.run(UserSettingsManager.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My splash activity:

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var presenter: SplashPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        presenter = SplashPresenterImpl(this)
        presenter.onCreate()
        window.setExitTransition(null)
    }

}
```

SplashPresenterImpl:

```
class SplashPresenterImpl(val activity: SplashActivity): SplashPresenter {

    override fun onCreate() {
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        if(auth.currentUser !=null && !auth.currentUser?.isEmailVerified!!) auth.signOut()
        if(auth.currentUser!=null) Handler().postDelayed({startMainActivity()},500)
        else Handler().postDelayed({startLoginActivity()},500)
    }

    private fun startMainActivity() = activity.startActivity(Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java))

    private fun startLoginActivity(){
        val activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
            Pair(activity.konkurlyText, "konkurlyTextTranstion"))
        activity.startActivity(Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java), activityOptions.toBundle())
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: The error comes from `RestrictiveDataManager.updateFromSetting(RestrictiveDataManager.java:46)`, which seems to be missing from the code you shared. Given that stack trace though, I'm not sure how Firebase would be involved in raising the exception.

Comment: https://wklejaj.pl/28251  That's not class which I created

Comment: That could be, but that doesn't mean we can help you. Based on the information you provided that best we can say is that there seems to be that a Facebook library you use has a problem parsing its settings: `parseAppSettingsFromJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

That exception means in somewhere of your code there is an Array with the limit of 15 indexes. But you have more than that.

That array might not be named as an Array in Kotlin anyway there must be some java codes working with Arrays in the background.

As a first step you may think to lower the count of characters in `"konkurlyTextTranstion"`

Best regards,
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrading from `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'` to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'` seemed to solve the issue.